# How to allow a user to only declare queues?

Tags: rabbitmq

How to define a rule in rabbitmq to limit a user so that he can declare queues but nothing more. As far as I understand permissions are defined via regular expressions and based on the resource name. But is there a way to define rules base on resource type?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) describes this in detail. But do you really want to allow the user only to declare queues? If he is not able to bind the queue to at least one exchange and consume from the queue, just declaring it will be of not much use.

Comment: Thanks @LutzHorn, I already read the documentation but I didn't find an answer to my question. Maybe I  can't understand the docs correctly. About your question, you are right that only declaring queues is not so useful. but I will bind queues to exchanges from a separate place and with another user. I'm trying to connect to rabbitmq server via stomp plugin and I need to limit the public users from declaring bindings by themselves.